# Unable create Screenshot of Craiglist with PhantomJS on Digital Ocean

Tags: phantomjs, digital-ocean, webpage-screenshot, craigslist

Have a very strange problem. Since 1-2 weeks I am unable to create screenshots of a Craigslist pages with PhantomJS on Digital Ocean. Does anybody have any idea what the issue could be and why it does not work anymore?

It always worked fine before and still works totally fine when I run it locally on my notebook. It creates the screenshot within 2-4 seconds. However running the same (no matter if in a special Docker-Container like the one used locally or installed directly on the host) on Digital Ocean keeps on loading forever and if I am lucky and wait long enough I get the screenshot after around 7-10+ minutes.

Tried it on different Droplets (existing & totally new) in different zones (SF & Frankfurt) but always have the same issue. Already contacted Digital Ocean about that. They were able to reproduce the issue but according to them nothing changed on their side and have so also no idea what could cause that. They blame PhantomJS or Craigslist.

It can be reproduced very easily. On a new Droplet (Ubuntu 14.04) the following code will install PhantomJS:

```
# Install dependencies
sudo apt-get install -y libicu52 libjpeg8 libfontconfig libwebp5 

# Install PhantomJS
cd /usr/local/share && \
curl -L -O https://github.com/bprodoehl/phantomjs/releases/download/v2.0.0-20150528/phantomjs-2.0.0-20150528-u1404-x86_64.zip && \
unzip phantomjs-2.0.0-20150528-u1404-x86_64.zip && \
ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.0.0-20150528/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
```

A very basic example script to create a screenshot of a product on craigslist. File called "test-screenshot.js" with this content:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://vancouver.craigslist.ca/van/ctd/5148995470.html';
page.open(url, function() {
  page.render('craigslist.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

To run the script: "phantomjs test-screenshot.js".

Thanks!

Comment: Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Thanks! But sadly none of them fires. It simply loads a very long time without any output and in the end the screenshot is there.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Craigslist is deliberately slowing traffic from Digital Ocean IPs.  In the DC area, the CL homepage takes > 55 seconds to load when I use my VPN hosted at Digital Ocean.  Without the VPN, load time is normal (< 1000 ms).  Other sites work properly through the VPN.

I assume this is a technical response to their recent lawsuits involving scrapers of their site.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! Also expected something similar. Had a long exchange with them but they always say it is definitely not them. Did have no idea there was a lawsuit but then makes sense then. I already started to migrate to a different provider. Because it works really everywhere except on their droplets.